# Removing python3.9 installed from third part

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3

Yesterday I have done several messes with my laptop, because I have uninstalled python3 on Ubuntu 20.04 because I have installed manually python 3.9 from the external repository https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-392/.

I have lost `ubuntu-desktop` because I have learnt that the OS uses python 3.8 as default for many applications. Ok, I have reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and python 3.8 after many efforts and the PC is working fine. But how can I remove python 3.9? I have tried the classical commands like `purge` or `remove` but they do not work.

When I give `python3.8` it gives me python 3.8 default version, but if I give `python3` it open a shell in python 3.9.2.

I have also tried the selection suggested in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047691/how-to-select-which-version-of-python-i-am-running-on-linux, but again it does not work. I just want to remove this python 3.9 package that I have installed from python.org.

When I run `which python3.8` I obtain the path `/usr/bin/python3.8`, while the new python3 I have downloaded from the previous link to pyhon.org, go to download and downloaded the python 3.9.2, pushing the button. I have extracted the file and followed the README with the commands `configure`, `make` and `make install`.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  so this is Ubuntu Core 20?  The problems you're describing however sound more like Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which is a different product to the *yy* based *snap* only releases such as Ubuntu Core 20.   Please clarify your release, as Ubuntu has had *yy* and *yy.mm* format releases since 2016 and refer to different products.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20 LTS Focal Fossa

Comment: FYI Focal Fossa is "20.04" (released in April 2020)...

Comment: We probably need a bit more information about where this other Python from python.org came from.  You said the command is `python3.8`?  Can you type `which python3.8` and update your question to indicate where it actually is?  I'm curious if you installed it as a normal user or as root.

Comment: @Ray I have done the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you followed the instructions for installing Python 3.9.2, presumably, you also did `make install` with `sudo`.  If you did that, then Python has been installed in `/usr/local/`.  The executable `python3` is placed in `/usr/local/bin/`, which is earlier in your `PATH` variable (i.e., the list of locations that are searched for when looking for programs).  That is why when you type `python3`, you get 3.9.2 .

You can confirm this by typing `env | grep PATH`.  One of the lines start with `PATH=` and that's the list of locations that are searched when looking for programs.  Paths earlier in the list have higher priority.  Your list is probably like mine.  `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin`.

So, to fix your problem, just erase all traces of Python 3.9 .  It is in `/usr/local/`.  Do this to remove them and yes, you will need to use `sudo`:

1. `sudo rm -f -r /usr/local/lib/python3.9`
2. `sudo rm -f -r /usr/local/include/python3.9`
3. `sudo rm -f -r /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.a`

Lastly, `cd /usr/local/bin/`.  You'll have to delete all of the relevant files here.  Unfortunately, they aren't contained in a directory that you can erase, so you will have to delete them one-by-one using `sudo`.  I believe these are the files you have to erase (I just installed Python 3.9.2 to replicate what you were seeing).  Obviously, don't erase anything else:

```
2to3              idle3    pip3.9    python3           python3-config
2to3-3.9          idle3.9  pydoc3    python3.9
easy_install-3.9  pip3     pydoc3.9  python3.9-config
```

After you've done all this, in a new shell, you can type `which python3` and it should report `/usr/bin/python3`.  If you then type `ls -al /usr/bin/python3`, you might see something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct  6 18:28 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8*
```

This is a symbolic link (i.e., a "Windows shortcut) that points `python3` to `python3.8`.

By the way, answer at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047691/how-to-select-which-version-of-python-i-am-running-on-linux) you showed is not relevant.  That's for the case when someone has installed two versions of Python from the Ubuntu repositories.  In your case, the second version was installed from the Python web site, outside of the Ubuntu repositories.  So the answer at this link doesn't help you.

In summary, when you downloaded Python from Python's web site, compiled it and installed it, it is placed in `/usr/local/bin/`.  It isn't "registered" in any way with the Ubuntu system.  All it did is put it in a location that is searched first before `/bin/`.  So, there's no single button that you can hit to remove all traces.  You just have to go into `/usr/local/` and manually remove it.  Since there will be other programs there, you can't remove all of it...you need to go in and remove a file or a directory at a time.  Once you do that, then Python 3.8 will be found first.

I think this is correct now; I hope this helps.

Comment: I want to remove python3.9, in order to have a single python3 version on my laptop because I need many libraries for programming. When I type `which python3` it returns `/usr/local/bin/python3`. When I type `which python3.9` it returns me `/usr/local/bin/python3.9` and when I type  `which python3.8` it returns `/usr/bin/python3.8`. I have done according your suggestion and when I give `ls -al /usr/bin/python3` it returns `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 mar 31 10:12 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8`. But when I type in my terminal `python3` it opens python3.9.2.

Comment: @TheOldJonny So, I've edited my response according to the information you provided.  I also installed Python 3.9.2 myself to see what you were seeing.  Now I understand what's going on.  I hope it's now correct -- let me know if you need further clarifications!

Comment: thank you. I have removed in `/usr/bin/local` every python3.9 files. Now when I run `python3`, it gives me a shell of `python3.8`.

Comment: @TheOldJonny You're welcome!  I'm happy to hear that it was of help to you!  I gave up installing from source a long time ago...unless I need a particular feature, I just wait until it's an official package so that upgrading it and erasing it is managed by Ubuntu...